# Android Studio travado

Tags: android, interface

Minha IDE do android studio não funciona direito, sempre que tento arrastar algum elemento para a interface ele trava e simplesmente não responde mais. O mesmo acontece ao tentar criar fragments pela interface, tenho que fazer tudo por código senão ele trava e só da pra fechar finalizando a tarefa. Já desinstalei, tentei versões diferentes e nada mudou, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Passei por isso também, bem recentemente.

Sempre que eu arrastava um componente novo para a `activity` o `android studio` travava, percebi que isso estava acontecendo porque aquele elemento não estava "off-line" e o `android studio` começava imediatamente a procurar dependências e adicionar no projeto, mas travava por falta de memória, processamento ou fé.

Para resolver isso, eu:

- Fechei tudo que estava aberto, deixei apenas o android studio.
- Fechei o meu projeto e abri um novo em branco, com apenas uma `empty
  activity`.
- Comecei a arrastar todos os componentes para essa `empty activity`, um
  a um, e em cada vez que eu arrastava eu esperava a IDE terminar de
  processar e baixar o que precisava da internet, mesmo que demorasse
  alguns minutos.

Depois de fazer isso com todos os elementos, e deixar todos disponíveis off-line, deletei esse projeto de teste e voltei para o meu, o problema parou de acontecer.

Nota de rodapé: provavelmente deve ter uma opção para baixar todas as dependências em algum menu ou opção do `gradle`, mas deve estar muito bem escondido porque não achei na minha IDE, então fiz esse gambiarra manualmente.